# Applying Datasheet view on a GridView Sharepoint

Tags: datasheet, spgridview

I was wondering if it is possible to apply Datasheet view onto a grid view found in an application page.
The grid View was used such that the data is filtered out such that only data concerning the user is viewed. I wish to see if it is possible to use DataSheet view along with a gridview such that The user can edit the data concerning him/her self.